# How to create an issue with Jira CLI including an attachment?

Tags: command-line-interface, jira

I'm creating a project template following this tutorial of Jira CLI: https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/How+to+create+projects+or+sets+of+issues+based+on+a+template

**What I need is to create an issue and add an attachment to it.**

Unfortunately, `createIssue` action doesn't has the parameter to add an attachment (https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCLI/Reference).

Although Jira CLI has an action called `addAttachment` which let you add a file to a issue which you already know the id, I don't have in advance my issue key.

Is there a way to create an issue and add an attachment to it, using in both case Jira CLI?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line below the created issue:

--action addAttachment --issue @issue@ --file "path/to/file"

The `@issue@` makes reference to the last issue referenced or created.